# ArcGIS Online: User manually add object/feature to see effect on surroundings

Tags: arcgis-online, dynamic-layer

I would like to make an web-app, I know the basics, but is it possible for users to  (1) add a temporary feature (in this case: physical building) and (2) directly solve/update the map to see the effects on the surroundings.

Ive done this in excel. Its a bit conditional. So whenever you add a feature, values around the grid will be affected and will directly update/solve in the web-page.

Is this possible, if so: are there examples or ways to do this?